# Updating person or group field no longer works if passing an array of FieldUserValue objects

Tags: sharepoint-online

For some reason updating person or group fields in sharepoint stopped working. This seems to happen only on SharePoint online as my on-prem version is working fine.

As soon as FieldUserValue value is added to the array i get this error when creating list item: "We couldn't find an exact match." It works if you pass a single FieldUserValue object.

I have checked and the field has "multiple users" option selected.

Here is the code example:

```
var arr = [];

var person = new SP.FieldUserValue();
person.set_lookupId(47);
var person2 = new SP.FieldUserValue();
person2.set_lookupId(58);

arr.push(person);
arr.push(person2);


  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
  oListItem.set_item('Title', defaults.Title);
  oListItem.set_item('person', arr);
  oListItem.update();

  clientContext.load(oListItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
  );


  function onQuerySucceeded() {
      alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
  }

  function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
      alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
          '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution. You have to use `SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('test1@test1.com')`.

Here is an example:

```
var user1 = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('test1@test1.com')
var user2 = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('test2@test2.com')
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
oListItem.set_item('person', [user1 ,user2]);
oListItem.update();
```

Answer (score -1):

`SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser` works with `LoginName` as well, so options are not limited to email only.